# Can I save any file in Parse javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am creating a web application, where in the text area the user can type in anything, and save it as any type of file (.doc, .txt, .java, .js and ect.) Sort of like Notepad, but its on the web. Can I save the file in Parse if the file type is java? I been only able to find tutorials on how to save image files in parse.

Here is my code for saving the file in Parse:

```
var usercode = req.body.code;
  newname = name+".java";

  var parsefile = new Parse.File(newname, {base64:usercode});
  parsefile.save().then(function(){
    console.log("File created and saved in Parse")
  }, function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
```

If my code is successful on my console I should see `file created and saved in parse`. However I don't get anything, not even an error msg.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can.

Parse stores PFFile's as binary data, as long as you have some way of serializing the data format when it goes in and comes back out it should be fine.

Source: https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html

Answer (score 0):

`Parse.file(Name, content)`. `content` must be in byte, these bytes must be stored in array.

So:

```
var bytes = []
for(x =0; x<content.length; x++){
 bytes.push(content.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

then `Parse.file(Name, bytes)`